# How to poll the asda website more frequently (bash)

Tags: bash

I make a script what will check the asda home delivery slots from the api

Here it is, I call it `get_slots.sh`

You have to start tor or if you don't then you have to get rid of the line about sock5 hostname (you can see tor port number in command line with ps) but if you don't use tor they might cancel your account if they get narky about you polling their website

obviously u have to change the vars at the top

Query parameters and api url was kind of found out with inspector in chrome while using their normal java script thingy for joe public, top secret NOT

```
#!/bin/bash

my_postcode="SW1A1AA"  # CHANGEME
account_id=18972357834   # JUST INVENT A NUMBER
order_id=22985263473    # LIKEWISE
ua='user_agent_I_want_to_fake'
my_tor_port=9150

#----------------

#ftype="POPUP"
#ftype="INSTORE_PICKUP"
ftype="DELIVERY"

format="%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00+01:00"
start_date=$(date "+$format")
end_date=$(date -d "+16 days" "+$format")

read -r -d '' data <<EOF
{
    "data": {
        "customer_info": {
            "account_id": "$account_id"
        },
        "end_date": "$end_date",
        "order_info": {
            "line_item_count": 0,
            "order_id": "$order_id",
            "restricted_item_types": [],
            "sub_total_amount": 0,
            "total_quantity": 0,
            "volume": 0,
            "weight": 0
        },
        "reserved_slot_id": "",
        "service_address": {"postcode":"$my_postcode"},
        "service_info": {
            "enable_express": false,
            "fulfillment_type": "$ftype"
        },
        "start_date": "$start_date"
    },
    "requestorigin": "gi"
}
EOF

data=$(echo $data | tr -d ' ')
url='https://groceries.asda.com/api/v3/slot/view'
referer='https://groceries.asda.com/checkout/book-slot?origin=/account/orders'

curl -s \
     --socks5-hostname localhost:$my_tor_port \
     -H "Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
     -H "Referer: $referer" \
     -A "$ua" \
     -d "$data" \
     $url \
    | python -m json.tool
```

anyway now i make another script to keep running it and mail me if any slots are available,

more vars u need 2 change at the top of this one

```
#!/bin/sh

me="my@email.address"
my_smtp_server="smtp.myisp.net:25"
#------------------------------------

mailed=0
ftmp=/tmp/slots.$$
while true
do
    date
    f=slots/`date +%Y%m%d/%H/%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S`.json
    d=`dirname $f`
    [ -d $d ] || mkdir -p $d
    ./get_slots.sh > $f
    if egrep -B1 'status.*"AVAILABLE"' $f > $ftmp
    then
        echo "found"
        if [ $mailed -eq 0 ]
        then
            dates=`perl -nle '/start_time.*2020-(..-..T..):/ && print $1' $ftmp`
            mailx \
                -r "$me" -s "asda on $dates lol" \
                -S smtp="$my_smtp_server" "$me" < $ftmp
            echo "mailed"
            mailed=1
        fi
    fi
    sleep 120
done
```

so i kind of naughty here cos i need the timestamp for slots with status available to put in the email ... and i really cba to parse the json properly so i just rely on its in the line before the status

like the pretty printed json puts the stuff in alphfabetical order and comes out with something like

```
                        "slot_info": {
                                STUFF
                            "slot_type": null,
                            "start_time": "2020-06-10T19:00:00Z",
                            "status": "AVAILABLE",
                            "total_discount": 0.0,
                            "total_premium": 0.0,
                                MORE STUFF
```

so yeah all i do is `egrep -B1`

oh yeah i also naughty hard coded 2020 not do proper regex for the year, cos if this is all still going on after 2020 i might as well just starve anyway so dont want to over engineer it

anyway as you can see once it already mailed me it still keeps running cos i want to store the json files and may be analise them laters , it just dont mail me again after that unless i re start it

anyway my question is my script only check every two minutes and i want it to check more often so i can beat people.

Comment: I love that you've shared this "life hack" solution with everyone, dubious as it may be with regards to ASDA's terms and conditions. There are improvements you could make to your script, but heck, if it works well enough for you, then that's great. It seems that your question is "how do I run my script more frequently". For that, we'd need to know how you're running your script in the first place, what OS you're on, etc.

Comment: @alecxs, after a short search, I haven't been able to find anything on asda.com suggesting that automated use of their site or services might be prohibited. I think it's encouraging that the OP recognizes that the tools he uses may cause harm, and we would do better to help him keep things efficient and low-impact than to ignore this.

Comment: lol the mate of mine sat there logged in pressing ctrl R to reload all day, server have to serve all the static ontent all over again every time i just go straight to the api and its me whats cousing the problem??

Answer (score 1):

okay sorted it the sleep 120 is 2 minutes i thought it was 1.2 minutes sorry forgot a minute is 60 seconds not 100 lol

oh yeah dont worry im not going to do this every 5 seconds like....!

just now i know the sleep is working properly i can change it to 60, still no more often than a lot of the people sat there re loading it manually believe me ......